# How to retrieve the uploaded data from the database and then display in my gridview using databind

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have made an file uploader to my localdatabse, which will successfully uploading any kind of files to my localdatabse. But now i need make this working with my grid view. How can i do it for a particular column and cell.

Codes for my file uploader to my localdatabse

```
 private void _tbnOpenImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileChooser.Filter = "ALL files (*.*)|*.*";
        fileChooser.InitialDirectory = "C:/Users/Sreejithmohan/Pictures/sample pics/";
            fileChooser.Title = "Uplaod Any File";
        if(fileChooser.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _PictureBox.ImageLocation = fileChooser.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void _btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString);
        byte[] imgData;
        imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(_PictureBox.ImageLocation);
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Imagetbl (Pics) VALUES (@DATA)",cnn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATA", imgData);

        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you want... what you want upload?

Comment: We don't upload data to a cell in a gridview. It goes to the database and would be retrieved from the database and then displayed in your gridview when you databind it. Can you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @SeanLange I need to retrieve the uploaded data from the database and then displayed in my gridview using databind

Comment: @Milanphir sorry, but I still do not understand. You want save in the database your grid? It's confused.

Comment: Does your grid already show an image and you are trying to update it with a new image or is this entirely new functionality you are adding?

Comment: @SeanLange . I just need to add a new functionality. How can i combine these both.

Comment: Well first of all you should have a second parameter in your image table so you know which parent row it belongs to. I hope you are using varbinary(max) and not the image datatype (it was deprecated in 2005).

Comment: To display it just pull it our your database in your query and create a dynamic image in the row from the data. Your question has a number of parts, which part(s) are you struggling with?

Comment: I just need to know how can i pull the inserted data to the gridview.